# KL divergence of categorical distribution with continuous inputs

Tags: distributions, kullback-leibler

I want to simulate a process. I have a probability distribution and I have d classes to choose from. The inputs of my distribution are 3d points and it maps each of these points to a d-dimensional density vector. This vector could be used to choose each of the classes and each point has a different density vector but the mapping is continuous.

Could my problem be shown in other way? And what is the KL-divergence of my model?

The base distribution $P$ is a uniform distribution, which means that for every point the density vector is $(1/d,..,1/d)$.